# App is crashing when trying to enable crypto in Matrix SDK iOS

Tags: swift, matrix

I am getting a crash when trying to enable crypto on iOS side using the SDK.

```
    let credentials = MXCredentials(homeServer: "http://matrix.org",
                                    userId: "@your_user_id:matrix.org",
                                    accessToken: "your_access_token")
    
    // Create a matrix client
    let mxRestClient = MXRestClient(credentials: credentials, unrecognizedCertificateHandler: nil)
    
    // Create a matrix session
    let session = MXSession(matrixRestClient: mxRestClient) 
    
    // enable crypto
    
    if session.crypto == nil {
            session.enableCrypto(true) { response in
                if response.isSuccess {
                    print("crypto is enabled")
                } else {
                    print("crypto is not enabled yet")
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the error getting printed when trying the above code.
[MXCryptoV2Factory] buildCrypto(session:migrationProgress:success:failure:): Missing required dependencies

Is there a way to resolve this issue. I am new to matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you find anything around this issue. I am stuck with this issue too. I am using latest Matrix SDK

Answer (score 0):

you can get Device ID through this:

```
matrixRestClient?.login(username: "@"+(User.shared?.profile.matrixUserName), password: (User.shared?.profile.matrixPassword)!, completion: { response in
        switch response {})
```

this function will return response and you will get device id from there. Issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

We get device id when we login.

```
let credentials = MXCredentials(homeServer: "http://matrix.org",
                                userId: "@your_user_id:matrix.org",
                                accessToken: "your_access_token")
```

//Edit that resolved the first crash

```
credentials.deviceId = device_id
```

// Create a matrix client

```
let mxRestClient = MXRestClient(credentials: credentials, unrecognizedCertificateHandler: nil)
```

// Create a matrix session

```
let session = MXSession(matrixRestClient: mxRestClient)
```

// enable crypto

```
if session.crypto == nil {
            session.enableCrypto(true) { response in
                if response.isSuccess {
                    print("crypto is enabled")
                } else {
                    print("something went wrong")
                }
            }
        }
```